# State-space model for health indicators

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am developing a discrete health indicator model with $n$ multiple observations. The methodology is as follows: Every hour, my patients insert a subjective perception of various health indicators (tiredness, hunger, anxiety...) ranging from 0 to 10. This gives me a vector each hour, and I want to develop a matrix A such that:

$x_{t+1} = A*x_t + e_t$

where $A^{nxn}$ is supposed to tell me how the various indicators correlate or interact, and $e$ is white noise/error term. Given multiple observations $x$, how can I best approximate the matrix $A$? In college, we mostly used models like this with $A$ already known, and the state needed to be approximated...

Comment: I wouldn't trust any health indicator based on the responses of a bunch of random people on a website. If you're serious about developing a health indicator, hire a mathematician to work one out for you.

Comment: This wikipedia link contains an overview on VAR models and how to estimate them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression

Comment: VAR model with 1 lag seems to be exactly what I am searching for. Now I just need a dedicated software and method to solve.